# Uniform integrability of product of random variables

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, uniform-integrability

> Let $\mathcal{Y}$ be a collection of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ that is bounded in $L^p$-norm, $p \in (1,\infty)$.  Fix $X \in L^q$ where $L^q$ is the dual space of $L^p$.
>
> Is $X\mathcal{Y} := \{XY : Y \in \mathcal{Y} \}$ also uniformly integrable?

I think the answer is yes, but I cannot seem to prove it.  Of course $\mathcal{Y}$ is uniformly integrable.  Any help is appreciated.  I was thinking of making use of Young's inequality: $ab \leq a^p/p + b^q/q$, for $a,b \geq 0$. Thus \begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[|XY| \mathbf{1}_{|XY| > k} ] &\leq \mathbb{E}[|XY| \mathbf{1}_{|X|^q/q+|Y|^p/p > k} ] \\ &\leq \mathbb{E}[|XY| (\mathbf{1}_{|X|^q/q> k/2} + \mathbf{1}_{|Y|^p/p> k/2}) ] \\ &\leq \lVert X \rVert_{q}\lVert Y\mathbf{1}_{|Y|^p/p> k/2} \rVert_{p} + \lVert Y \rVert_{p}\lVert X\mathbf{1}_{|X|^q/q> k/2} \rVert_{q}. \end{align*}

Hence, $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{Y \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathbb{E}[|XY| \mathbf{1}_{|XY| > k} ] = 0+0$?

Comment: Why do you think that $\|Y1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}\|_p$ converges (uniformly in $Y$) to $0$ as $k \to \infty$? Clearly, $$\|Y1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}\|_p =\left( \int_{|Y|/p>k/2} |Y|^p \, d\mathbb{P} \right)^{1/p}.$$ Since we do not have $L^r$-boundedness for some $r>p$, we cannot use Markov's inequality... and the uniform integrability of $\mathcal{Y}$ gives only $$\lim_k \sup_{Y} \int_{|Y|/p>k/2} |Y| \, d\mathbb{P}=0.$$ (You would need $|Y|^p$ instead of $|Y|$)

Comment: Yes, I could not justify that step.  So do you think that the result is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of your approach is fine, but your estimate for the term $\mathbb{E}(|XY| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2})$ is too rough (see the above comment). Here is a possible way to deal with it:

Fix $R>0$, then

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|XY| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}) &\leq R \mathbb{E}(|Y| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}) + \mathbb{E}(|XY| 1_{|X|>R})  \\ &\leq R \mathbb{E}(|Y| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2})  + \|X 1_{|X|>R}\|_q \|Y\|_p. \end{align*}

Since $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$ is uniformly integrable and bounded in $L^p$, we have

$$\sup_{Y \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathbb{E}(|XY| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}) \leq R \underbrace{\sup_{Y \in \mathcal{Y}}  \mathbb{E}(|Y| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2})}_{\to 0 \, \text{as $k \to \infty$}} + \|X 1_{|X|>R}\|_q  \underbrace{\sup_{Y \in \mathcal{Y}} \|Y\|_p}_{=:M<\infty},$$

i.e.
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{Y \in \mathcal{Y}} \mathbb{E}(|XY| 1_{|Y|^p/p>k/2}) \leq M \|X 1_{|X|>R}\|_q \xrightarrow[R \to \infty]{} 0.$$